# Windows form application crashes unexpectedly C#

Tags: c#

Here is my code. I dont think there is anything wrong with the code. Sometimes it runs fine but sometimes it crashes unexpectedly.

```
namespace searchingConsoleWFA
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    searchingConsole.Class1 objj = new searchingConsole.Class1();
    List<searchingConsole.Class1> obj = new List<searchingConsole.Class1>();

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        String compName, tit, conName, phone, fax, addr, pCode, city, reg, cntry;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)
             || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text)
             || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox5.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox6.Text)
             || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox7.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text)
             || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox9.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox10.Text)
            )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Complete Information", "Invalid");
        }
        else
        {
            compName = textBox1.Text;
            tit = textBox2.Text;
            conName = textBox3.Text;
            phone = textBox4.Text;
            fax = textBox5.Text;
            addr = textBox6.Text;
            pCode = textBox7.Text;
            city = textBox8.Text;
            reg = textBox9.Text;
            cntry = textBox10.Text;

            obj.Add(new searchingConsole.Class1(compName, tit, conName, phone, fax, addr,
                pCode, city, reg, cntry));
            MessageBox.Show("Company Added!", "Registered");
        }
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        textBox5.Clear();
        textBox6.Clear();
        textBox7.Clear();
        textBox8.Clear();
        textBox9.Clear();
        textBox10.Clear();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String compName, conName;
        compName = textBox11.Text;
        conName = textBox12.Text;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox11.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox12.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Company Name and Contact Name", "Invalid");
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox11.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Company Name", "Invalid");
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox12.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Contact Name", "Invalid");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
            {
                if (obj[i].getCompanyName() == compName && obj[i].getContactName() == conName)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Match Found", "Search Result");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Match Not Found", "Search Result");
                }

                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox2.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is the form I have created. On clicking 'Cancel' the program should exit. The 'OK' button is for searching and the 'Apply' button is for recording the data in some data structure.

The problem is, if I create a record first and then exit then the program exits fine, but if I exit first it crashes. Similarly if some record is searched the program runs fine, but if text fields are left empty then program crashes.

Any Help?

Comment: can you update which `button_click` corresponds to which button ?

Comment: have you put break points in the code especially in the portion where you stated that `if I exit first it crashes` it sounds like a `Failure to Dispose()` of created objects.. a good way to test this is where ever you are newing up an instance, set that instance to `null` if it does not `Impliment IDisposable` and see if it exits gracefully without throwing that exception[Environment.Exit(Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @tchrikch buuton1 is 'OK', button2 is 'Cancel', button3 is 'Apply'.

Comment: I'd recommend a debugger for your coding problem, a designer for your design problem, a workplace sensitivity training class for your variable naming problem.

Comment: rename your buttons to be more meaningful when you get a chance too.. `btnCancel, btnOk, and btnApply`  would be more meaningful in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think on a WPF application you don't use `Environment.Exit(0)`, you use `Application.Exit()`.

Let's see:

- `Environment.Exit(0)`-> "Exits this process and gives the underlying operative  system the specified exit code". I have allways used this on on Console Applications.
- `Application.Exit()`-> "Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed".
  You must use this one on WPF.

**NOTE:** Also instead of those `if` and `else` i think you could try to do a `try catch` block. Use it like this:

```
    try
    {
            //Code goes here
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
            throw; //Say here what you want the message to show like: Insert a text there
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Everyone else was just trash taking about my coding methods. Thanks again

Comment: @EL323 - I read the above comments, and while they might have seemed critical of your "coding methods", they (almost) all had good points on habits that you should develop as a coder. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `Application.Exit()` instead of   `Environment.Exit(0)`.
If it still crashes , put your exit code in try catch expression and read the inner exception . i ll show you your problem.

Comment: Environment.Exit() has to take an argument

Comment: sorry Application.Exit(). What about the result of try catsh?

Comment: if it helps you check it as a helpful answer. thanks :)